# Retrieve details of my wordpress site

Tags: blog, domain, user-access

I recently created a wordpress site for starting a blog. But I cannot see it listed in my wordpress account with my other blogs. So either I used some other email address that I can't track or the blog has been disconnected from my account due to something that I did. How do I access that wordpress site again?

Answer (score 0):

Either Check with your hosting provider or connect with FTP to your website if you have privilege to do so.

Via FTP You can gain access to all your files and then  restore it